# Which share icon is most appropriate for web?

Tags: icons, sharing

Now days there are multiple viable share icons available, but they are mostly mobile OS specific (iOS, WP, Android...). I wonder which icon should I use for the web that most of the users would recognize?

[image: Multiple share icons]

*Image source: https://bold.pixelapse.com/minming/share-the-icon-no-one-agrees-on*

Has anyone done any A/B tests on how users respond to different ones?

Its a simple album page where you can get links for each album/image and then share it with a friend, nothing special, just popup on click of an icon.

Comment: Sometimes the answer can also be *none*, but whatever icon you choose, adding the word *Share* will almost certainly help.

Comment: Opinion of course, but I'd say the third one is the most recognizable.

Comment: I can't recommend it, but I sure wish a clean version of the old Android icon (4th) would've caught on. It seems like the most intuitive option used to date. My least favorite is Apple's new one -- it looks more like 'export' to me.

Comment: @Doorknob: I was about to write the third one is the *least* recognizeable, but that may be because I've just been working with a software today where more or less exactly that icon was used to mean "connections" (between nodes, in a graph drawing context).

Comment: Did you take the image from this [post on fastcodesign.com](http://www.fastcodesign.com/3031872/why-isnt-there-a-standard-share-button)? Either way, you might want to attribute it.

Comment: Have you considered *not* annoying your users with those useless sharing options ? If the content is worth sharing, it's very easy to copy/paste the URL into whatever social media client the user is using.

Comment: @AndréDaniel: I second this. In particular, the only truly universal sharing option that should be shown is a permalink to the resource (because the current URL in the address bar might not be that). Just see what the *Share* option on SE answers does.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper to be honest I don't like SE's share option either, it leaks my user ID and gives an extra redirect to clients who click on the link (and on slow mobile networks, that extra redirect may last for several seconds).

Comment: @AndréDaniel: True, I hadn't realized it did that. I had always presumed the first number in SE's share URL is the question ID, and the second one is the answer ID - I didn't realize one of them is my user ID and hence, I take back my comment that SE does it the right way. Please read my last sentence as "Just see what the *Share* option on SE answers, imagining that it shows a link that points just to the question + answer without giving away one's user ID, does."

Comment: @O.R.Mapper but there is still the useless redirect... even on desktop I find them annoying and on mobile it's worse due to the increased latency. The right way to do it is simply to put a permalink to the resource in the address bar, eventually using Javascript if it's a web app.

Comment: @AndréDaniel: When you look at a question on an SE website, how are the permalinks of all answers to the question, and the question itself, supposed to simultaneously appear in the address bar? Also, the address bar might contain additional info, such as anchors that you were navigating to.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper clicking the share button should point to the answer's anchor, automatically changing the address bar's URL.

Comment: @AndréDaniel yes I thought of not having many sharing options. This is why I am not including any social share sh*t. It will be a simple icon which will open a popup with permalinks to resources. Url to image, url to album, embeddable code... - This is not accessible through url alone. Users are not able to strip part of the url they don't want to share (just think of youtube music sharing when you are listening to playlist)...

Comment: Apple has _move_ icons where semi-public download with automatic announcement would be one option out of many. New Google and MS emphasize the _connection_ of nodes where it does not matter much who is author and who is consumer. Old Android was a mix of the former two concepts, i.e. distribution or broadcast. Old MS adds an inappropriate notion of _obscurity_ and, like the open one, indicates a 1:1 action of passing an item. None of these is appropriate for all settings that would be described as _sharing_.

Answer (score 17):

**Use the second or third icon.**

If you read the article you took that image from (https://bold.pixelapse.com/minming/share-the-icon-no-one-agrees-on) you'd see that the author recommends using the second icon, the "Outgoing Tray" over the third "Three Dots" icon because the arrow helps convey sharing even to users who haven't seen the icons before and haven't learned each icon's meaning.

In either case you will want a "Share" label on the icon to make the intent obvious.

Comment: I disagree with using the mobile icons for a web platform.  As a web user who doesn't share anything via my phone, if I saw either of those icons on a website, I'd be completely flabbergasted at what they could possibly do.

Comment: Agree with this answer. Anecdotal of course, but I'd instantly know what two or three is doing (similar icons are used all over the place), and I've never seen most of the others. The first icon confuses me whenever I pick up the iPad we use for testing here at work. Literally every time. I think the direction of the arrow connotes something different to me than a share.

Comment: I like your suggestion. Also, the 3rd icons represent a connection between your users. Which also simbolizes (as a side effect) the act of sharing something between them, and consequently to others. To me, the 3rd one is a better choice than the 2nd. The 2nd is more like "send" and ultimately can be somewhat confused with "download". The 4th one is also a good choice, but it isn't "pretty" like the 3rd.

Comment: Well, using the second which is already now an out of date icon doesn't sound like the wisest of plans. Choosing the Android icon might be the best choice indeed if you really need an icon as the same icon is used in the material design icon set which I have been seeing pop up online more and more.

Comment: I used to think the iOS icon meant "Forward" since it looked like the icon you would see in an email app (which was close enough to the real function), and I never used the Android one until someone told me what it did because I thought it related to "networking" or something similar. Again, with a label either icon is acceptable. The article also points out that the first icon resembles the "upload" counterpart to a "download" icon.

Answer (score 13):

For websites, most places tend to just use icons like the ones below.

[image: Share icons]

This reference is from [this article](http://contohblognih.blogspot.com/2014/02/cara-memasang-kode-share-facebook.html) talking about adding them to a [Blogspot](https://www.blogger.com/home).

In your case, if you're just sharing between one person, I would just use the word "`Share`" or the phrase "`Share with a friend`". It's clear, to the point, and easy for your user to understand. If you do want an icon of some kind, there is also the idea of a +(plus) sign that most users universally understand as a website "`Share`" button.

Comment: Personally, I would **not** interpret a plus sign as "share". I would assume it meant "add" something. That "something" would depend on context (add a comment at the end of an article, add an attachment to a comment box, etc.), and there are many contexts where a "share" button makes sense while an "add" button would completely befuddle me.

Comment: Sometimes these can be slow to load because they use an iFrame. If that's a concern there are other ways to do this other than what is specifically linked to here.

Comment: I almost went to refresh the page/go to a new page the second I saw those icons. I'm so used to seeing it at the bottom of the page, or at least the main content, my brain recognizes them as more of an "end of the page" signal than anything for actually sharing content.

Comment: Don't forget there are also privacy concerns... all these social media buttons track all users and even though they promise to respect Do Not Track (or at least, that's what Twitter is telling me) I wouldn't trust them.

Comment: When I see the Facebook icon, I never know what will happen when I click on it.  Or at least I am surprised most of the time what happens.  Sometimes I get sent to the company's Facebook page (least likely option that I would want.), I might end up liking a particular post for a company (somewhat likely) or I might be given the option to post "it" ("it" hopefully means a post on my timeline linking to the web page I'm viewing), or sometimes nothing happens!  Or it says I posted it on my timeline and it never shows up.

Answer (score 2):

No tests here but I would choose the android one (quite often used on different websites no matter the OS)
If its multi sharing, the best choice is to let appear some social icons that everybody knows and use a "+" icon if you don't have enough space.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you primarily use Android devices?

Answer (score 2):

The last one seems best, but it's not very popular, so you can't really use it.

The second looks confusing, reminds me of emails, reply, outbox.

Answer (score 2):

There's surprisingly little data on this out there that I could find.

The only study I read about was **[Microsoft's](https://medium.com/microsoft-design/the-iconography-of-sharing-183a1ad9c6f1)**, which doesn't provide concrete data. Microsoft says:

> We looked at the **icons users were seeing out in the wild** and tested
>   similar variations to see which icons best represented what it meant
>   to share. We A/B tested them against the old share icon in the Photos
>   app, with and without labels...   The best performing icon was our new
>   icon, a rectangle housing a swooping arrow that indicates motion out
>   of the rectangle.

I assume that, as both the three-dot icon that Google popularized and Apple's upward-pointing icon are widely used, Microsoft tested those metaphors out too. And given that the Photos app is on every Windows 10 computer by default, I assume that these tests were on quite a large audience.

The icon they found best represented sharing was **icon #2, with a right-pointing arrow**.

An opinion piece on [Co.Design](https://www.fastcodesign.com/3031872/why-isnt-there-a-standard-share-button) agrees, though it doesn't have any data to back up its claim. I also find the arrow to be the most representative. It might be because a right-pointing arrow is similar to the forward icon in email clients, which serves basically the same function.

It's also telling that, even though it's not used on iOS anymore, it's still used by Facebook and YouTube (Google's own property) as the share icon, **even on Android** (as of Dec. 2017). It's also the icon metaphor that FontAwesome, a popular web icon pack, uses.

Comment: In a comment on Microsoft's article, the UX designer behind the study notes that "... even though **most people were most familiar with their own platform’s icon**, there was also a leading candidate regardless of platform, which is the icon we landed on. :)"
that means that Microsoft DID test the respective Android and iOS icons

Answer (score 1):

My preference is [Font Awesome's share icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/share), which is pretty close to the second one in your list.

The logic being that Font Awesome is a really popular library, and if we all use it's share icon then users will instantly know what it means when they come to our website/use our app etc.

Comment: I think it would be good to note that popularity of a library may not necessarily mean it should be used. It should be based upon the most widely used icons on sites. This also does not answer the question, have you conducted any A/B tests on user responses to icons?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing something is a rather abstract concept which can't really be encapsulated in an icon (at least based on all the examples seen so far). That's where the problem with all of these icons comes in; if you can't get the point of sharing across to a user in an icon, the icon won't mean anything unless it's explained, and that is not good design. Despite having seen (and clicked on) all of those icons before, I had absolutely no clue any of them were supposed to mean share until I read your question.

The point is, with any of these icons, you're very likely to have people who don't understand what the icon means. I would just go with a button that says "share". It's simple and straightforward, and no one will be able to misconstrue it. None of the icons given will get the point across to the user quite as well as the word "share" will.