# Which is the most "shareable" icon out there

Tags: icons

Our company have three main platforms, the web, Android and iOS.

It's based on listings where you can perform some actions, one of them being sharing, since I saw this question in '15 ([Which share icon is most appropriate for web?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/71779/which-share-icon-is-most-appropriate-for-web)), I would like to ask, which icon should we use?

We use this one for **Desktop** right now : [image]

Android: [image]

iOS: [image]

These icons were taken from the internet, they not correspond to the real ones in our platforms/devices.

Now, the question is, are we using the good ones in each platform? Should we use only one for all platforms? Is there any recent evidence or icon sharing research?

This is the most recent study I have found, but iOS now have more market share I dunno.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to use an icon? It's often a clever idea to use an icon together with a label or even just a label. For example, here on Stack Exchange it's just the word "share" which is instantly recognizable and nothing your users need to guess about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your company should have a consistent experience through all platforms. Pick one icon and add it to your general corporate experience language.

I don't think you'll find any academic evidence for which icon to pick as they will all be relative to the project/product. If there were one 'best' icon for sharing then we would all be using it and there wouldn't be any others.

If you're looking for a definitive answer in your case the you need to test with your users.

You could try putting all three icons on a page and asking them to select the share icon.

Once you have your results, make the choice and commit it to your pattern library so that all platforms offer a consistent experience.

I'm sure that someone else will argue that trying to match the platform native language would be better but that just leaves you vulnerable to their changes and you should be in control of what your users want.

Comment: I like the idea of putting all 3 icons on a page and seeing which gets the most clicks -- An A/B/C test using Google Optimize or the like could be a nice way to do it.

Comment: I had to hunt high and low for the 'share' word on this page. Thought it wasn't there until I spotted it. I would go for a hybrid - the icon and the word share. This is what the BBC do.